# How to tell the future controller with which the object will work

Tags: angularjs, href

My problem is that I would like to inform future controller of the object will have to deal with. But without creating for each object a different path as it may be a lot of them and without ID in the path. But how do you tell the controller to know that the building was called.

html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-nested" ng-repeat="building in faculty.buildings">
        <a href="#structure_department" title="">
            <span class="menu-item-parent text-menu-resol"> {{ building.name }}</span>
        </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
.when("/structure_department", {
            templateUrl: "views/building.html",
            controller: "BuildingController"
})
```

I have no idea, maybe you already did something similar ?
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

If i can understand your question correctly, one easy way to do this is to use a service.  first build the service, and then inject it into both the controller you are using, and the controller you will be using.  All you have to do then is set which building name is in use to the service, and then get it when you are using your other controller.

Create Your Service:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.service('DataService', function () {
    var buildingName = '';

    function getBuildingName() {
        return buildingName ;
    }

    function setBuildingName(buildingname) {
        buildingName = buildingname;
    }

    return {
        setBuildingName: setBuildingName,
        getBuildingName: getBuildingName,
      }
});
```

And in your controllers:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('buildingController', ['$scope', 'DataService',
        function buildingController($scope, DataService) {
 DataService.setBuildingName('buildingName');
}]);
```

AND:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('futureController', ['$scope', 'DataService',
        function futureController($scope, DataService) {
$scope.buildingName = DataService.getBuildingName();
}]);
```

Another way it can be done is through route params.  Look at the angular documentation for $routeParams and you can pass it in the url.  Just inject the route param service into your controller and you can get the building name from the url as a parameter.